# Descriptive geolocation service recommendations

Tags: api, geolocation, maps

I am developing a system that needs the next information:

- List of countries
- List of regions for each country.
- List of main cities for each country

For example:

```
[{
    name: "United States"
    regions: [
        {
            name: "Oregon"
            cities: [
                {
                    name: "Albany"
                },
                {
                    name: "Aloha"
                },
                {
                    name: "Beverton"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I was getting the information using **The API geodb-cities-api.wirefreethought.com**, but I want to know if some developers use another API (or services) to get this information (Geolocations descriptive).

Greetings!

**postscript**: It doesn't matter whether they are paid or open sources.

Comment: The country information, I used the ISO-3166 (Countries with Regional Codes)

Comment: The regions for each country, I used the ISO 3166-2 .